# Annotating count of unique object occurences in Django ORM query

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

In a Django app of mine, users post photos saved as `photo` objects. Viewers can then post comments under each photo, saved as `photocomment` objects that have a foreignkey on `photo` objects.

I'm trying to write an ORM query where to each photo object requested, I append the number of unique comments it garnered. Unique implies comment by a unique `user_id`. I.e. if the same guy/girl commented 1000 times, it' still 1 unique comment.

How do I accomplish that?

---

So far, I've come up with the following:

```
relevant_photos = Photo.objects.filter(id=set_of_ids)
PhotoComment.objects.filter(which_photo_id__in=relevant_photos).annotate(unique_comment_count=Count("submitted_by")).distinct("submitted_by")
```

I feel this can't work because I'm not really counting `distinct` commenters here. What would be the correct way to do this? Trying to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#id7) with [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by). For example

```
PhotoComment.objects.annotate(count=Count("submitted_by", distinct=True)).order_by("submitted_by")
```

Answer (score 1):

The model structure will help, but this may works:

```
relevant_photos = Photo.objects.filter(id=set_of_ids)
PhotoComment.objects.filter(which_photo_id__in=relevant_photos).annotate(unique_comment_count=Count("submitted_by", distinct=True))
```

Being comment model something like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
   ...
   submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
   ...
```